Dovecot dh.pem file "too short"?
When a client tried to connect to the server (dovecot versions 2.3.11) they get an error that the dh.pem is too small. I've tried regenerating the file using the following command:
openssl dhparam -out ./dh.pem 4096
There is no change after restarting Dovecot to read the new file. I've even tried a much larger file (9064) and got the same result. When I run doveconf -n -P it shows the correct path to the dh file. And of course the ssl_dh_parameters_length parameter is no longer used.
I have other ssl issue but they involve the cert and key files so I'm trying to get this error out of the way before tackling those. Not sure what to try next, thanks for any helpful suggestions.

When asking questions about dovecot configuration, it is usually a good idea to include the output of the doveconf -n command.. so we can see you configuration.

You probably specified a filename, where you should have instructed dovecot to read the contents of a file.
Note the difference between ssl_dh = literal and ssl_dh = </path/to/file.pem .

That being said; if you are generating or configuring custom DH parameters at all, you are doing something wrong. It was once believed there was a point in the flexibility to permit custom parameters, but all it produced was broken crypto. By now any new system you setup should be using an ssl toolkit that just uses the fixed parameters from RFC7919, such as OpenSSL in version 3.0 and later.
